# Non-plaintext YAML editor

Tags: linux, yaml

I need to work with YAML files but I get the willies when working with YAML's loose, inconsistently-spaced, strangely-keyed, ruby-esque format.

What software exists to open and edit YAML as key-value data tree?

My target platform is Debian Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 Compatible), or possibly Windows software that runs well in Wine.

Comment: fwiw, I gave up on a structured yaml editor, just write json and call it .yml

Answer (score 1):

Use VS Code (or [Codium](https://vscodium.com/) as open source alternative) and install the plugin [YAML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml) from RedHat. Though it doesn't allow to edit YAML as key-value data tree, it has a lot of advantages when it comes to editing YAML.

It "Provides comprehensive YAML Language support to Visual Studio Code, via the yaml-language-server, with built-in Kubernetes syntax support."

Feature list:

```
YAML validation:
    Detects whether the entire file is valid yaml
    Detects errors such as:
        Node is not found
        Node has an invalid key node type
        Node has an invalid type
        Node is not a valid child node
Document Outlining (Ctrl + Shift + O):
    Provides the document outlining of all completed nodes in the file
Auto completion (Ctrl + Space):
    Auto completes on all commands
    Scalar nodes autocomplete to schema's defaults if they exist
Hover support:
    Hovering over a node shows description if provided by schema
Formatter:
    Allows for formatting the current file
    On type formatting auto indent for array items
```